# Cannot edit source files locally without checking out file on TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

Me and 2 colleagues are using TFS and VS 2013 on a shared project. Me and my Colleague "Bill" are able to edit files and check them in whenever we like. But colleague "Bob" cannot do this. They appear as "locked" in his solution unless he goes into TFS and specifically checks out the file. Me and Bill dont need to do this, we can simply edit the files and if we both try and check in the same file it notifies us of merges. Bob has the same TFS permissions as us, and as far as I can see the same visual studio settings.
Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a workspace issue.

Bob needs to change his workspace from a server workspace to a local workspace. If he's using VS2010 or earlier, he will not have that option -- local workspaces are only supported in VS2012 or later.

Here's an MSDN link on how to configure local workspaces:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/05/set-local-workspaces-as-default-when-upgrading-to-tfs-2012.aspx

Comment: How does bob do this. He did originally have VS2010 installed. He still has I think but he works off 2013, but im guessing the 2010 is working in the background.

Comment: If he created the workspace in VS2010, it was created as a server workspace. He'll need to convert it to a local workspace. I'll update my answer with a link on how to accomplish that.

Comment: I followed the MSDN link and did what it said, and the solution works. I can confirm. Thank you.